# Remove .php extension from index.php. where .htaccess file is to be located?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have code in .htaccess file

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

My directory like..

www/careers/index.php

And i have putten .htaccess file in www/careers directory

But it's not working..

i think it's not working only at localhost...

Please help me my thing is true or i have done some mistake in code...or directory??

Answer (score 1):

99.9% of the time, you'll only need one copy of ExpressionEngine's index.php file, and it should live in the webroot:

`www/index.php`

Your .htaccess file with those mod_rewrite rules should be placed in the same directory as index.php:

`www/.htaccess`

Those mod_rewrite rules will work for all URLs that are children of that directory, including /careers.